# setrlimit() not affecting spawned std::threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, setrlimit

I am currently working on a pipeline which loads and transforms multiple images at once. As this is happening to many images at the same time (1440) the memory footprint is quite heavy. I therefore tried to implement a memory management system based on setrlimit, however it doesn't seem to affect the spawned threads (std::thread) as they will happily ignore the limit - I know this because of calls to getrlimit() in the threaded functions - and eventually cause my program to be killed. Here is the code I use for setting the limit:

```
void setMemoryLimit(std::uint64_t bytes)
{
    struct rlimit limit;
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &limit);

    if(bytes <= limit.rlim_max)
    {
        limit.rlim_cur = bytes;
        std::cout << "New memory limit: " << limit.rlim_cur << " bytes" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        limit.rlim_cur = limit.rlim_max;
        std::cout << "WARNING: Memory limit couldn't be set to " << bytes << " bytes" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "New memory limit: " << limit.rlim_cur << " bytes" << std::endl;
    }

    if(setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &limit) != 0)
        std::perror("WARNING: memory limit couldn't be set:");

    // included for debugging purposes
    struct rlimit tmp;
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &tmp);
    std::cout << "Tmp limit: " << tmp.rlim_cur << " bytes" << std::endl; // prints the correct limit
}
```

I'm using Linux. The man page states that setrlimit affects the whole process so I'm kind of clueless why the threads don't seem to be affected.

Edit: By the way, the function above is called at the very beginning of main().

Comment: Aside from the "actual question", why do you think this is the right solution? Surely the right solution is to not start as many threads or load as many images at once, or whatever you need to do to limit your memory usage? Assuming `setrlimit` actually worked, what will happen is that your process either gets killed or can't allocate memory somewhere "random", which is clearly a pretty awful way to deal with the issue...

Comment: I do check the available memory before loading. If there is no memory left, loading halts - at least in theory. My problem is that the existing limit is ignored by the threads and I don't know why or how to work around it.

Comment: Please show a minimal buildable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Not reproducible here, see [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aec50f8f68a66065).

Comment: The code posted here seems to work just fine. Are you, perhaps, getting the actual memory limit wrong? (My code: https://gist.github.com/Leporacanthicus/11086960)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was quite hard to find as it consisted of two entirely independent components:

1. My executable was compiled with -fomit-frame-pointer. This will result in a reset of the limit. See the following example:

   ```
   /* rlimit.cpp */
   #include <iostream>
   #include <thread>
   #include <vector>

   #include <sys/resource.h>

   class A
   {
       public:
           void foo()
           {
               struct rlimit limit;
               getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &limit);
               std::cout << "Limit: " << limit.rlim_cur << std::endl;
           }
   };

   int main()
   {
       struct rlimit limit;
       limit.rlim_cur = 500 * 1024 * 1024;
       setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &limit);
       std::cout << "Limit: " << limit.rlim_cur << std::endl;

       std::vector<std::thread> t;

       for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
           A a;
           t.push_back(std::thread(&A::foo, &a));
       }

       for(auto thread : t)
           thread.join();

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Outputs:

   ```
   > g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer rlimit.cpp -o limit
   > ./limit
   Limit: 524288000
   Limit: 18446744073709551615
   Limit: 18446744073709551615
   Limit: 18446744073709551615
   Limit: 18446744073709551615
   Limit: 18446744073709551615

   > g++ -std=c++11 -pthread rlimit.cpp -o limit
   > ./limit
   Limit: 524288000
   Limit: 524288000
   Limit: 524288000
   Limit: 524288000
   Limit: 524288000
   Limit: 524288000
   ```
2. For the image processing part I work with OpenCL. Apparently NVIDIA's implementation calls setrlimit and pushes the limit to rlim_max.